# How use img source from the values in the json response?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to pass a url value in JSON as an image tag in my HTML using javascript.

Following is the json response, i get:

```
{
    "remaining": 50,
    "cards": [{
        "suit": "SPADES",
        "value": "2",
        "code": "2S",
        "images": {
            "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2S.svg",
            "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2S.png"
        },
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2S.png"
    },
    {
        "suit": "CLUBS",
        "value": "QUEEN",
        "code": "QC",
        "images": {
            "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.svg",
            "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.png"
        },
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.png"
    }],
    "success": true,
    "deck_id": "ag5x22svcp8g"
}
```

I can access and parse all other json data except 'images' as an actual image.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = parse.cards[0].suit + ", " + 
parse.cards[0].value
document.getElementById("card2").innerHTML = parse.cards[1].suit + ", " + 
parse.cards[1].value


document.getElementById("card1image").src= cards[1].images.png;
```

Here is the HTML tag i wish to put it into.

```
    <img id="card1image"/> //<---- this one
    <div id="card1"></div>

    <img id="card2image">
    <div id="card2"></div>
```

It does not throw an error, it just simply does not display the image. I'm pretty sure I've done the getElemntByID call wrong. any information would be helpful.

It is worth noting that the url inside the JSON object is different on reload as it pulls a random card from a deck. Tried storing the response URL in a variable and still could not get it working.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.

Comment: Try displaying in console, whether ```cards[1].images.png``` gives the image url. Then check whether that is a valid image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code. You just write your line like this

`parse.cards[1].images.png`

You just missed the word `parse` in your code.

```js
var parse = {
  "remaining": 50,
  "cards": [{
      "suit": "SPADES",
      "value": "2",
      "code": "2S",
      "images": {
        "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2S.svg",
        "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2S.png"
      },
      "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/2S.png"
    },
    {
      "suit": "CLUBS",
      "value": "QUEEN",
      "code": "QC",
      "images": {
        "svg": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.svg",
        "png": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.png"
      },
      "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/QC.png"
    }
  ],
  "success": true,
  "deck_id": "ag5x22svcp8g"
}

document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = parse.cards[0].suit + ", " +
  parse.cards[0].value
document.getElementById("card2").innerHTML = parse.cards[1].suit + ", " +
  parse.cards[1].value


document.getElementById("card1image").src = parse.cards[1].images.png;
```

```html
<img id="card1image" />
<div id="card1"></div>

<img id="card2image">
<div id="card2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! This saved me so much time. I'm also working with a service worker so it's being a bully about updating the content on the page consistently.

Comment: If my code works for you, then you can upvote it as well as mark it accepted answer. Happy to help you :) @AdamNieuwenhuizen

Comment: done :) also seemed to have an issue with it being picky over wanting to use the .svg image versus png.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `parse.cards[1].images.png`? You are missing `parse`